# Android Firebase password reset error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting an error whenever I try to enter an email into an alertdialog. I am trying to get it to send a recovery password to the email entered. Here is my code and error message I am getting

Code:

```
public void PassResetViaEmail(View view)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Settings.this);
    alertdialog.setTitle("Reset password");
    alertdialog.setMessage("Enter email below");

    EditText input = new EditText(this);
    email = input.getText().toString().trim();
    alertdialog.setView(input);

    alertdialog.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ResetEmailSender();
        }
    });

    alertdialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertdialog.show();
}

public void ResetEmailSender()
{
    auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(
        new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "We have sent you instructions to reset your password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Failed to send reset email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Error:

```
04-14 02:25:40.842 20031-20031/com.safariagaming.flix E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.safariagaming.flix, PID: 20031
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.safariagaming.flix.Settings.ResetEmailSender(Settings.java:105)
    at com.safariagaming.flix.Settings$2.onClick(Settings.java:91)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:161)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: `auth` is null.

Comment: Correct, you need to use [getInstance](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/EmailPasswordActivity.java#L70-L70) to initialize your `auth` variable.

Comment: @Jeff That seemed to fix something, but it is still giving me an error. This time saying this: https://pastebin.com/YjSFDubU I think it's saying that the String email is empty, but that cannot be true because the user is putting something into it. Also I declared it as String email = "dummyEmail@gmail.com"

Comment: I copied the code and error from the linked pastebin documents into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem:

```
EditText input = new EditText(this);
email = input.getText().toString().trim();
```

"email" only exists inside "PassResetViaEmail", not inside "ResetEmailSender". Try this:

```
alertdialog.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ResetEmailSender(email);
        }
    });
```

and on "ResetEmailSender":

```
public void ResetEmailSender(String email)
{
    auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(
        new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "We have sent you instructions to reset your password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Failed to send reset email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

I'am assuming that "auth" is correctly instantialized somewhere else.